# Make numbers in a string into a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I need your help.
I'm trying to make a userscript that finds numbers with >x digits, and turnes them into links.
Links are structured like this *http://domain.com/[number]*

So far I've managed to find the links, put them in an array, but I'm stuck trying to replace the numbers in the text with the links.

```
$("p").each(function(){

    var string = $(this).text();
    var getNum = string.match(/(\d+)/g);

    for(i=0; i<getNum.length; i++){
        if(getNum[i].length >= 5){



            //for testing the array
            $('#result').append(i+" : " + getNum[i]+" ");
        };
    }

});
```

Any advice/solutions?

https://jsfiddle.net/9qt6z3x8/4/

Comment: So, you want this: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9qt6z3x8/9/)? Or is the `'#result'` paragraph required for some reason? Your question doesn't quite explain what you want (or what that element is for).

Comment: Yeah, I could kind of tell from all the downvotes. 
Thank you for at least commenting what was unclear :) 
The accepted answer is what I ment to communicate. hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're going for. Need to replace the text inside with `<p>` with the new markup with the `<a>` tags.

```js
 $("p").each(function(){
        var string = $(this).text();
  var getNum = string.match(/(\d+)/g);
        
  for(i=0; i<getNum.length; i++){
   if(getNum[i].length >= 5){
                
                //for testing the array
                $('#result').append(i+" : " + getNum[i]+" ");
                
                // replace with link
                string = string.replace(getNum[i], 
                  '<a href="domain.com/'+getNum[i]+'">'
                   +getNum[i]+'</a>');
   };
        }
        
        $(this).html(string);
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> this is a 1234 numbers 123455 test 11234343323</p>

<div id="result">array= </div>
```

Comment: This was perfect! 
The odd thing is that this is what I was thinking and tried.. Don't know what I did wrong.. oh well.
Thank you!! you the man

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you were trying to replace them inline, I've updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9qt6z3x8/17/), but all you need is that regular expression and to just replace it right away with a link:

```
$("p").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(\d{5,})/g, '<a href="http://domain.com/$1">$1</a>'));
});
```

**EDIT:**

more efficient use with the jquery library thanks to @DavidThomas

```
$('p').html(function(index, html){
    return html.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<a href="http://domain.com/$1">$1</a>');
})
```

Comment: Why not: `$('p').html(function (index, html) { return html.replace(/regex/, replacement); })` to avoid the repeated calls to `$(this)` and use of `html()`?

Comment: @DavidThomas because I focus-visioned on what was given and preserved the original loop. Your way is much cleaner and more efficient and I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler solution...

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\b(\d{5,})\b/g, '<a href="http://domain.com/$1">$1</a>');
```

```html
<p> this is a 1234 numbers 123455 test 11234343323</p>
```

Comment: Very nice ! could you explain /\b(\d{5,})\b/g ?

Comment: @user3426703 `\b` means whole-words (word-boundaries), `\d{5,}` means numbers with a min length of 5, the `g` means don't stop after the first occurrence